# OOP Page Loader PHP Template Engine

Tags: php, oop

I'm currently working on a simple PHP Template Engine and I have to come to a decision, but I'm not really sure how to solve this.

I've written a class called “Page“, which loads the page components of the current page. This is how it looks like now:

```
<?php
class Page {
    private $currentPage;

    private $header;
    private $content;
    private $footer;

    const CONTENT_DIR = 'content/';
    const CONTENT_FILE_EXT = '.php';

    public function __construct(Header $header, Content $content, Footer $footer) {
        $this -> header = header;
        $this -> content = content;
        $this -> footer = footer;
    }

    public function getCurrentPage() {
        if(!isset($this -> currentPage)) {
        if(isset($_GET["p"])) {
            try {
                $this -> setCurrentPage(trim($_GET["p"]));
                } catch(FileNotFoundException $e) {
                }
        }
        else
            $this -> setCurrentPage('start');

        }
        return $this -> currentPage;            
    }

    private function setCurrentPage($pageName) {
        if(file_exists(self::CONTENT_DIR.$pageName.self::CONTENT_FILE_EXT)) {
            $this -> currentPage = $pageName;
        }
        else
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
    }
}
?>
```

Now, I have a second class „PageFactory“:

```
<?php
class PageFactory {
    public function build() {
        $header = new Header();
        $content = new Content();
        $footer = new Footer();

        return new Page($header, $content, $footer);
    }
}
?>
```

It just doesn't feel right to pass the current page (the page to be loaded). Should I better use a static function to return the current page? The problem is that I need this function in other classes, too (e. g. the menu). I'd have to pass the current page again via parameter.

Thanks for any advises!

Comment: Any solution that entails `static` is the **wrong** option. Apart from that .. emm ... what exactly is your question amd how does it relate to OOP (aside from "I have a class") ?

Comment: So, you should **never** use `static`? To clarify my question: Is it the best way to pass the current page as parameter in `Header`, `Constructor` and `Footer`?

This question is OOP because it's about relationship and dependency between classes…

Comment: Well, the `static` methods and variables within a class are essentially global. As for you problem, you might try watching [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0).

Comment: Thanks @tereško, that lecture was pretty helpful. I improved my code a bit (and edited it above). But the problem is still not solved: how should I pass the current page to the page components (header, content and footer)? According to Demeter I should do something like `new Header($currentPage)`, right? But actually, it's an attribute of Page?

Comment: To me it looks that you `Page` instance is basically dealing with URL routing. At the same time the names of classes give impression that you want to be managing [php templates](http://codeangel.org/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html) there. What exactly is the `Page` class supposed to do?

Comment: `Page` is currently routing URLs __and__ merging `Header`, `Content` and `Footer`. Should I separate these things in two classes?